# How can I remove the current marker if another place is selected?

Tags: java, android, location, google-maps-markers

I have a autocomplete search fragment and a marker is added when there is a selected place, now what I want to do is to make the first marker to be remove if another place is selected. Tried doing some if statements but the first marker still exist, I might be doing something wrong. Any comments or suggestion would be greatly appreciated!!

Autocomplete fragment with marker

```
 autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());

                // Get the LatLng of the selected place
                LatLng selectedPlaceLatLng = place.getLatLng();

                // Define a new CameraPosition with desired zoom level
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(selectedPlaceLatLng) // Sets the center of the map to the selected place's LatLng
                        .zoom(20) // Desired zoom level
                        .build();

                // Move the camera to the new position
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                markerSelectedLoc = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(selectedPlaceLatLng)
                        .flat(true));
                markerSelectedLoc.setTag(0);

            }
```

Comment: `markerSelectedLoc.remove()` is how you would remove a marker - so **prior to** adding the current one try `if (markerSelectedLoc != null) markerSelectedLoc.remove();`

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking your time commenting. Tried this before but the first marker is gone and now after trying it again it seems that I should remove first then add new marker for it to work!! THANK YOUU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I should remove the marker first then add again the marker if its removed, here is what I did.

```
 // Remove the previous marker if it exists
                if (markerSelectedLoc != null) {
                    markerSelectedLoc.remove();
                }

                // Create a new marker for the selected location
                markerSelectedLoc = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(selectedPlaceLatLng)
                        .flat(true));
            }
```